# Adding an icon or image on a preview quick action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I wonder if there is any way of adding an icon to the quick actions associated with a peek & pop preview (reachable through 3D touch).

I have created a couple of preview actions using:

```
UIPreviewAction(title: "Save".localized, style: .Default)
```

but I fail o find a way of adding any type of icon or image to the buttons making them more understandable.

[image]

*Example: The second row has an icon (photoshopped)

as I want it.*

**An example of an app achieving this** (the swedish app hemnet which I have no association to)

[image]

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to do that.

Comment: Added an example of an app proving that it is indeed possible

Comment: tommys: changing the style to UIPreviewActionStyleSelected achieves the checkmark icon. I don't think it's possible to insert other icon there